Snowflake python worksheet with package from stage (Office365-REST-Python-Client)
I know very similar questions have been asked, but all attempts to import this non-Anaconda package into a Snowflake Python worksheet give the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named...".

I used pip download Office365-REST-Python-client and zipped all of the wheel files together.
Uploaded the file "Office365_rest_python_client_2_5_11.zip" to a stage.
Started a Python worksheet in the same db and schema as the stage, went to the packages menu and and loaded the zip file.  Here's a screen shot to show it worked:



At this point the Snowflake docs state that I cannot use session.add_import, session.add_packages or session.add_requirements to add packages. "Instead, you add those files to a stage and reference them in your code."

But still, import Office365_rest_python_client_2_5_11, or the real name of the package that I've used elsewhere import office365.sharepoint.client_context return the same "ModuleNotFoundError".
I've also tried to make sure the stage is in the sys.path with:
session.custom_packages_usage_config = {"enabled": True}
import_dir = sys._xoptions.get("snowflake_import_directory")
sys.path.append(import_dir + "Office365_rest_python_client_2_5_11.zip")

None of which make a difference.  It also makes no difference if the import is with the rest of the imports at the top, or inside the main handler. I must be missing some conceptual piece of this workflow.  Has anyone successfully loaded a non-Anaconda to a worksheet specifically?
Here's the entire worksheet:
import sys
import snowflake.snowpark as sp
import snowflake.snowpark.functions as sff

def main(session):   

    session.custom_packages_usage_config = {"enabled": True}
    import_dir = sys._xoptions.get("snowflake_import_directory")
    sys.path.append(import_dir + "Office365_rest_python_client_2_5_11.zip")
    
    import Office365_rest_python_client_2_5_11 as shrp
    
    dataframe = session.table('information_schema.packages') \
                        .filter(sff.col("language") == 'python') \
                        .filter(sff.col("runtime_version") == '3.11')   
    return(dataframe)

Many thanks!

Turns out there is a little gem of a utility to take care of the path, extraction & loading.  This utility is from snowflake-labs called wheel_loader.py: https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/snowpark-extensions-py/tree/main/extras/wheel_loader.
So the bulk of the work is just getting the worksheet to see the packages, then it's pretty easy.

Make an internal stage.
Download the package, don't install: pip download packagename.
The downloaded package should be a wheel file (.whl), or a bunch of wheel files.  Delete all the wheels except for the one that is the package you downloaded - the rest are dependencies that you probably don't need.
Upload the wheel file to the internal stage.
From the python worksheet, go to the packages -> stage menu and type the path & filename: @STAGE_NAME/packagename.whl  The checkbox should turn green and let you add the package.
Repeat for wheel_loader.py.
In your worksheet, here's the part that uses wheel_loader to load your downloaded package:

import wheel_loader

wheel_loader.load('Office365_REST_Python_Client-2.5.11-py3-none-any.whl')
import PACKAGENAME

That's it!
